# What is the physical location of the compiled assembly of my project?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am beginner trying to understand basics what is dotnet net framework. i came accross concept of assembly. i have searched to understood from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct%28VS.71%29.aspx?

1.As far as I understand that means when I create a project and compile it, that the complied code is what we call an assembly? Here I mean when I compile my code "Debug" folder is created inside my bin directory. Where it resides?

1. Can some one please help me to know how do i see assembly physically? i mean in my e.g. windows application project.
2. I read assembly can be .dll or .exe is it when i created class library project will form .dll assembly after compilation and when i create e.g windows,console,web application project etc will form .exe assembly after compilation. Am i understood correct?
3. while understanding framework i came accross statement CIL code is housed in Common Language Infrastructure Assembly.
   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_(CLI)?
   Is CLI assembly itself assembly which maintains or is intended for above our created application assemblies. i am talking about assemblies which i m asking in question 1,2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compilation, by default the assembly is located underneath the project in a /bin/Debug or bin/Release folder depending on the configuration.

i.e.

c:\YourProject\bin\Debug\YourProject.dll

c:\YourProject\bin\Release\YourProject.dll

Comment: Thanks :) that was relief. What abt Point3 ??

Comment: If you want some fantastic information about the CLI, have a read through the specification on the CLI at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm